# Anharmonic quantum oscillator with momentum perturbation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, anharmonic-oscillators

Given the following quantum oscillator for a particle with mass $m$, and perturbation $-\gamma P$ ($\gamma$ is a constant):

$$H=\frac{P^2}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2X^2-\gamma P$$

One could find the eigenvectors and eigenstates using perturbation theory of first order. However, I'm interested in the exact solution. $H$ can be written as follows:

$$H=\frac{(P-m\gamma)^2}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2X^2-\frac{m\gamma ^2}{2}.$$

So if we denote $P'=P-m\gamma$, and $X'=X$, then we can solve for the eigenfunctions normally since the transformation is canonical, namely: $[X',P']=i\hbar$. The eigenfunctions and eigenenergies are given by:

$$\phi _n (x')=\left(\frac{\beta ^2}{\pi}\right)^{1/4} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n n!}}e^{-\frac{\beta^2 x'^2}{2}}H_n(\beta x')$$

$$E_n=\hbar \omega \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{m\gamma ^2}{2}$$

Where $\beta^2=\frac{m\omega}{\hbar}$, and $H_n(\beta x')$are Hermite polynomials. The question is how do I find the representation of the eigenfunctions using the original $x$ variable? One way to find the exact solution is by using $P'=e^{\frac{- im\gamma X}{\hbar}}Pe^{\frac{im\gamma X}{\hbar}}$, and since $e^{\frac{\pm im\gamma X}{\hbar}}$ commute with $X$, then one can write $H$ as:

$$H=e^{\frac{- im\gamma X}{\hbar}}\left(\frac{P^2}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2X^2\right)e^{\frac{ im\gamma X}{\hbar}}-\frac{m\gamma ^2}{2}$$

Hence the eigenfunctions are $e^{\frac{- im\gamma X}{\hbar}}|n\rangle$, or $e^{\frac{- im\gamma x}{\hbar}}\phi _n(x)$. How can one derive that given $\phi_n (x'), X'=X, P'=P-m\gamma$, and without using $P'=e^{\frac{- im\gamma X}{\hbar}}Pe^{\frac{im\gamma X}{\hbar}}$? If we substitute $x'=x$ we get the wrong result. Is there something faulty with my derivation above? I would appreciate some help with this, thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the existing approach?  You already have the eigenfunctions as $e^{\frac{- im\gamma x}{\hbar}}\phi _n(x)$; what else do you need? Or how and where do you get a wrong result?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong; Using the transformation above for $P$, and $X$, we get a "new" $H$ for a particle with  $X'$ and momentum $P'$, such that $<x'|P'|f>=-i\hbar \partial_{x'}f(x')$. Or a new problem where: $H=\frac{P'^2}{2m}+\frac{m\omega ^2 X'^2}{2}-0.5m\gamma^2$.  The solution is then given by $\phi_n (x')$ mentioned above. This is the eigenfunction in the $|x'>$ basis, how do I find its representation in the $|x>$ basis?

Comment: You started with your original hamiltonian $H$ and you show that $H=e^{\frac{- im\gamma X}{\hbar}}H_0e^{\frac{ im\gamma X}{\hbar}}-\frac{m\gamma ^2}{2}$ for $H_0$ the unperturbed hamiltonian, so you know $e^{-\frac{ im\gamma X}{\hbar}}|n⟩$ must be eigenfunctions of $H$. To calculate their wavefunctions, simply take $$⟨x|e^{\frac{- im\gamma X}{\hbar}}|n⟩=e^{-\frac{ im\gamma x}{\hbar}}⟨x|n⟩.$$ I still don't see what you're confused by, though.

Comment: Maybe this would make it clearer; Suppose the perturbation was something like $-q\epsilon X$, then if we complete the square for $X$, and define $U=X-\frac{q\epsilon}{m\omega ^2}$, then Schrodinger's equation is given by:

$(-\frac{\hbar ^2}{2m} \frac{d ^2}{d {u}^2} +\frac{1}{2} m\omega ^2 u^2)\phi '(u)=(E+\frac{q^2 \epsilon ^2}{2m\omega ^2})\phi '(u)=E'\phi '(u)$

Then we know the solution for this harmonic oscillator as $\phi'_n(u)$, and its representation in the $|x>$ basis is given by $\varphi_n(x)=\phi'_n(u=x-\frac{q\epsilon}{m\omega ^2})$.

Comment: In this case, after finding the solution in the $|y>$ basis we returned to the "original" basis by substituting $u=x-\frac{q\epsilon}{m\omega ^2}$. In my question above, and assuming one "forgot" that $P'=e^{\frac{-i \gamma mx}{\hbar}}Pe^{\frac{i \gamma mx}{\hbar}}$,we solved a new problem where $H=\frac{P'^2}{2m}+\frac{m\omega ^2 X'^2}{2}-0.5m\gamma ^2$, and found the solutions $\phi'_n(x')$. But I cannot say that the solution in the $|x>$ basis is $\varphi _n(x)=\phi'_n(x'=x)$ and this confuses me... I hope this made it clear, thanks anyways.